# Получить возраст на дату визита

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В запросе выполняю код

`trunc(visit.visit_date) - trunc(patient.birthday)` получаю возраст пациента в днях на момент посещения поликлиники. Как преобразовать дни в года? Т.е. нужно получить сколько было полных лет на момент посещения.

Comment: 1000 дней - сколько полных лет? И тут точно так же.

Comment: @Эникейщик 1000 - это очевидно что два полных года. А вот 730 дней - уже совсем даже неочевидно.

Comment: @Akina а вот для это есть visit_day и birthday

Comment: @Эникейщик Угу. А потому разница в днях - неприменима. Надо тупо считать разницу годов, а потом при необходимости корректировать (минус раз) в зависимости от разницы даты-месяца.

Answer (score 0):

```
trunc (MONTHS_BETWEEN (trunc(visit.visit_date), trunc(patient.birthday)) / 12)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ краткое пояснение, как работает ваше решение

Answer (score 0):

При помощи DatePart получаем год визита и рождения, и вычисляем разницу.

Она или равна искомой или на 1 больше, если в текущем году ДР ещё не наступил.

Проверяем что ДР ещё не наступил так: месяц рождения больше месяца визита иои месяц совпадает, но день визита меньше дня рождения. Если этот так, то вычитаем единицу.

`DatePart (visit.visit_date, DP_YEAR) - DatePart (patient.birthday, DP_YEAR) - CASE WHEN DatePart (visit.visit_date, DP_MONTH) < DatePart (patient.birthday, DP_MONTH) OR DatePart (visit.visit_date, DP_MONTH) = DatePart (patient.birthday, DP_MONTH) DatePart (visit.visit_date, DP_DAY ) < DatePart (patient.birthday, DP_DAY ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`